# Exclude states from country code in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

The following code gives the same price no matter what tax for the selected countries. Example: If a product cost 100$ (we've set prices inclusive local 25% vat), the price will be 100$ even if it's 0%, 12%, 25% or 50% tax. The price is always the same. The code below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', 'custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );
function custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $boolean ) {
    // Avoiding errors on admin and on other pages
    if( is_admin() || WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return $boolean;

    // Defined array of countries where the boolean value should be "false"
    $countries = array( 'AX', 'AT', 'BE', 'BA', 'HR', 'CZ', 'DK', 'FI', 'GR', 'HU', 'IS', 'IE', 'IT', 'LU', 'NL', 'PO', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'SE', 'GB');

    // Remove field $countries
    if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_billing_country(), $countries ) ) {
        $boolean = false;
    }
    return $boolean;
}
```

Problem:
Spain has 2 states that should not have tax whatsoever, even not the local 25% that we have set. So in the example above, the 100$ should cost 80$ (removing 25% local Swedish tax).

How would I go about to exlcude the state of: GC & TF?

Comment: If you are OK with plugins, you can try this one "Conditional Shipping for WooCommerce". The feature you are asking might not available with free version. But you can tweak the code of plugin according to your needs.

Comment: @maddy23285 Thank you for your reply, no I rather not use plugins as I want full control because there are other things I need done, thanks anyway.